# How to send api request from test class to Main class in salesforce?

Tags: api, salesforce, integration-testing, apex

**Class :**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/fetch_status/*')
global class RestDemo{

    @HttpGet
    global static Account getResult(){
        
        Account account;
        String accountId = '';
        RestRequest restReq = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse restRes = RestContext.response;
        
        // reading url
        try{
                //accountId = restReq.params.get('accountId');
                accountId = restReq.requestURI.substring(restReq.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);        
                
                account = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId Limit 1];
                
                if(account != null){                                       //checked whether any record is returned or not
                        restRes.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(account));
                        restRes.statusCode = 200;
                        
                  }else{    
                       /* String account_not_found= '{"message":"Not Found"}';
                          restRes.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(account_not_found);  */ 
                          restRes.statusCode = 404; 
                    }                 
            }
        catch(Exception ex){
            restRes.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(ex.getMessage());
            restRes.statusCode = 500;
            }   
     return account;
    }
}
```

**Test Class :**

```
private class RestDemoTest {

    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Testing5');
        insert acc;
    }
    

    static testMethod void testGet() {
    //case 1 when the id is valid
        Account acc = [ SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1 ];
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();             
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/api/fetch_status/' + acc.Id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        Account acct1 = RestDemo.getResult();
        system.assertEquals(acct1.Name, 'Testing5');
        
     // case 2 when the id is not present 
        String str_id = '0012x000004UjZX';
        Id id = Id.valueOf(str_id);
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/api/fetch_status/' + id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        Account acct2 = RestDemo.getResult();
        system.assertEquals(acct2, null); 
        
    }
}
```

**I want to test the test case 2 where the account with the random id is not present.
But while testing the test class (in test case 2 )it is giving exception.**

In this i used an existing id and changed it a little.So while test case2 runs it should go through the else statement of the main class but it is throwing exception (catch statement,Tested it in salesforce developer console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`account = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId Limit 1];`

The way you written it `account` will never be null. It'll just throw "List has no rows for assignment to SObject".

Change to this

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId Limit 1];
if(!accs.isEmpty()){
   // return 200;
} else {
   // return 400;
}
```

If you query that way it'll always come as List. It can be empty list but it will be a list (not null). Assign query results to single Account/Contact/... only if you're 100% sure it'll return something. Or catch the exceptions